# Add Control in Widgets Sub-Panel in Customizer

Tags: widgets, theme-customizer

Is it possible to add controls to sub panels of the widgets panel in the customizer? If yes, how do I address them? The widget area would be named “top-widget-area”

Neither addressing:

```
'panel' => 'widgets-top-widget-area'
```

nor

```
'section' => 'widgets-top-widget-area'
```

in `$wp_customize->add_control` work.

Do you have an idea?

Comment: Needing some clarification: You're wanting to add controls to the panel that [lists the sidebar areas](http://imgur.com/M618tXl)?  Or you mean the [panel before that](http://imgur.com/A4WMEnG)?

Comment: Hi @jami0821, Directly into the panel for a specific widget area. For example I want to add a control to the bespoken "top-widget-area" to define how many columns it should have.

Comment: WP-Admin » Customizer » Widgets Panel » Top Widget Area

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the section would be addressed with 'section' => 'sidebar-widgets-top-widget-area' ... so you need the sidebar-widgets- in front of the widget area name.

However, since it is the widgets panel, everything except the widget areas active on the page your are at are set to display: none; and need to be set to: display: block !important;

Answer (score 0):

@richwp , I asked a similar question and got a detailed answer from Weston Ruter, who actually works on the Widgets customizer panel in core.  He created a writeup, a video, and a github repo with source code in order to answer my question (which was an awesome thing to do).  Here is the link to the writeup he did:  [link]https://make.xwp.co/2017/02/08/adding-meta-fields-to-a-widget-sidebar-section-in-the-customizer/